# .Net Printing from a web site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wpf, zebra-printers

Scenario- I have a website that tracks/manages data stored in a DB(I know this covers 90% of websites :)).  I have users that need to print specialized labels and barcodes.  The app will need to print to a specialized Zebra RFID printer as well as a specific printer for bar codes.  All users must use IE 7. Only 3-4 users will print these items. I want to give the user a button they press and then the barcodes/reports are just printed.

Question-
I can create all the files that need to be printed on the server but can I use an XBAP to automate the specialized printing?  If not is there any other way?

Comment: Several things to clarify:

- Does your printer have driver?
- How do you normally print to these devices?
- How do you send the data to the printer?

Answer (score 1):

Access to special hardware from within Internet Explorer is not always easy - even for something as basic as a printer. You can try using the built-in printing facilities of IE7 - but you are likely to run into formatting and layout problems when printing something like barcodes.

XBAPs run an a sandbox and have limited access to hardware as well - but you may be able to print from one - it all depends on whether you need access to any Win32 print or device APIs.

A gauranteed way to implement something like this is using an ActiveX control - but that a much more complicated thing to implement - and it will only work on Internet Explorer - and on a machine that is configured to allow ActiveX controls to run.